# Reseting a config option on vue-flatpickr programatically

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, flatpickr

I have a vue date component that is composed of a vue-flatpickr-component. When I pass config options in as props, of course, they work as expected, however, if want to change one of the config options which should be possible, it won't propagate down. I'm not a Vue guru, any advice would be helpful.

I'm using a page component in a Laravel app, it shouldn't be relevant, however, just in case someone answers with vuex or vue-router, those won't work here.

Here are the form elements in play from page.vue:

```js
<material-select
    name="specialist"
    label="Specialist"
    default-text="CHOOSE HOMEVISIT SPECIALIST"
    :options="staffMembers"
    v-model="form.specialist"
    :validation-error="form.errors.first('specialist')"
    class="mb-4"
></material-select>
<div class="w-1/2">
    <material-date
            label="Appointment date"
            name="appointment_date"
            v-model="form.appointment_date"
            :validation-error="form.errors.first('appointment_date')"
            class="mb-4"
            :external-options="{
                enable: this.appointmentDates,
            }"
    ></material-date>
    <pre>{{ this.appointmentDates }}</pre>
</div>
```

Here is the computed property driving the config change:

```js
computed: {
    appointmentDates(){
        if(this.form.specialist !== null){
            return this.availableDates[this.form.specialist - 1]
        }
        return []
    },
```

When a different home visit specialist is chosen, it will update with Vue's reactivity.

I have a computed property changing the config options. Here are the props data and the relevant computed property from the MaterialDate.vue file:

```js
import flatPickr from 'vue-flatpickr-component';
import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';
export default {
components: {
    flatPickr
},
props: {
    value: String,
    label: String,
    validationError: String,
    name: {required:true},
    optional: {
        default: false
    },
    externalOptions: {}
},
data() {
    return {
        defaults: {disableMobile: true,},
        options: this.externalOptions
    }
},
computed: {
    config(){
        return Object.assign({}, this.defaults, this.options)
    },
```

This will of course never update the enabled dates option because the prop is immutable, I need to get access to the `set(option, value)` section of the wrapped by vue-flatpickr-component. However, my Vue kungfu is not really strong enough to source dive it to see how I might access it and programatically call `set('enabled', [new dates])`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @nnnmmm, that reads better. I don't know how to upvote it or pass along points for taking the time.

Comment: Thanks for the props (pun intended) :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you shouldn't code when you are tired :) But Hopefully this will help someone at some point. I was over thinking this. Data is passed down through props, and if controlling data changes it has to be reflected in the propagated data. Much like v-model with it's value prop.

So instead of binding the config object on this.options which doesn't stay hooked to it's prop value that it was initialized from, the computed function should be calculated from the prop which will change based on the new passed in options prop.

so simply change the computed function to:

```js
computed: {
    config(){
        return Object.assign({}, this.defaults, this. externalOptions)
    },
```

and remove the data element.

... Elementary

Sorry for the cheese it's late and I feel relieved.